# Facebook api posting to an Album

Tags: facebook, image

The code below posts to a photo album but also posts in the main timeline. Is there a way to only post to the album.

```
<?php

    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
      'app_id' => 'xxxxxxxx',
      'app_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxx',
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
      //'default_access_token' => '{access-token}', // optional
    ]);


    $data = [
      'message' => 'My awesome photo upload example.',
      'source' => $fb->fileToUpload('./img/sandy.jpg'),
    ];


    try {
      // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
      $response = $fb->post('/me/photos/test', $data, '{token}');
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }

    $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

    echo 'Photo ID: ' . $graphNode['id'];
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: Not working from January of 2017.** [More info here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41516241/facebook-graph-api-2017-image-uploaded-to-timeline-photos-instead-of-given-alb/41611147#41611147)

---

It's an old post, and I've searched a different topic, but if I'm here...

```
$data = [
    'message' => 'My awesome photo upload example.',
    'source' => $fb->fileToUpload('./img/sandy.jpg'),
    'published' => false,
];
```